# Java collections convert a string to a list of characters

Tags: java, string, collections

I would like to convert the string containing `abc` to a list of characters and a hashset of characters. How can I do that in Java ?

```
List<Character> charList = new ArrayList<Character>("abc".toCharArray());
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You will have to either use a loop, or create a collection wrapper like `Arrays.asList` which works on primitive char arrays (or directly on strings).

```
List<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
Set<Character> unique = new HashSet<Character>();
for(char c : "abc".toCharArray()) {
    list.add(c);
    unique.add(c);
}
```

Here is an `Arrays.asList` like wrapper for strings:

```
public List<Character> asList(final String string) {
    return new AbstractList<Character>() {
       public int size() { return string.length(); }
       public Character get(int index) { return string.charAt(index); }
    };
}
```

This one is an immutable list, though. If you want a mutable list, use this with a `char[]`:

```
public List<Character> asList(final char[] string) {
    return new AbstractList<Character>() {
       public int size() { return string.length; }
       public Character get(int index) { return string[index]; }
       public Character set(int index, Character newVal) {
          char old = string[index];
          string[index] = newVal;
          return old;
       }
    };
}
```

Analogous to this you can implement this for the other primitive types.
**Note that using this normally is not recommended, since for every access you
would do a boxing and unboxing operation.**

The [Guava library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) contains [similar List wrapper methods for several primitive array classes](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/PrimitivesExplained#Primitive_array_utilities), like [Chars.asList](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.6-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Chars.html#asList%28char...%29), and a wrapper for String in [Lists.charactersOf(String)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.6-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#charactersOf%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 84):

In Java, starting from Java 8, you can use streams.
List of Character objects:

```
List<Character> chars = str.chars()
    .mapToObj(e->(char)e).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And set could be obtained in a similar way:

```
Set<Character> charsSet = str.chars()
    .mapToObj(e->(char)e).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Importing `java.util.stream.Collectors` is required for this snippet to work.

Comment: The [`chars`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#chars--) method was introduced in Java 9 - it doesn't exist in Java 8.

Comment: @SteveChambers It does exist on `CharSequence` in Java 8: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#chars--

Comment: @Unmitigated Ah good point.

Answer (score 37):

The lack of a good way to convert between a primitive array and a collection of its corresponding wrapper type is solved by some third party libraries.  Guava, a very common one, [has a convenience method to do the conversion](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Chars.html#asList%28char...%29):

```
List<Character> characterList = Chars.asList("abc".toCharArray());
Set<Character> characterSet = new HashSet<Character>(characterList);
```

Comment: Looks like I have reinvented the wheel here ... I suppose `Chars.asList` does about what the `asList` method in my answer does.

Comment: Also in Guava is `Lists.charactersOf("abc")` which is is a little shorter and doesn't make us call `toCharArray()`

Answer (score 17):

Use a Java 8 `Stream`.

```
myString.chars().mapToObj(i -> (char) i).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Breakdown:

```
myString
    .chars() // Convert to an IntStream
    .mapToObj(i -> (char) i) // Convert int to char, which gets boxed to Character
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); // Collect in a List<Character>
```

(I have absolutely no idea why `String#chars()` returns an `IntStream`.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435833/why-is-string-chars-a-stream-of-ints-in-java-8

Answer (score 10):

```
List<String> result = Arrays.asList("abc".split(""));
```

Answer (score 8):

The most straightforward way is to use a `for` loop to add elements to a new `List`:

```
String abc = "abc";
List<Character> charList = new ArrayList<Character>();

for (char c : abc.toCharArray()) {
  charList.add(c);
}
```

Similarly, for a `Set`:

```
String abc = "abc";
Set<Character> charSet = new HashSet<Character>();

for (char c : abc.toCharArray()) {
  charSet.add(c);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Create an empty list of Character and then make a loop to get every character from the array and put them in the list one by one.

```
List<Character> characterList = new ArrayList<Character>();
char arrayChar[] = abc.toCharArray();
for (char aChar : arrayChar) 
{
    characterList.add(aChar); //  autoboxing 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without boxing if you use [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/):

```
CharAdapter abc = Strings.asChars("abc");
CharList list = abc.toList();
CharSet set = abc.toSet();
CharBag bag = abc.toBag();
```

Because `CharAdapter` is an `ImmutableCharList`, calling `collect` on it will return an `ImmutableList`.

```
ImmutableList<Character> immutableList = abc.collect(Character::valueOf);
```

If you want to return a boxed `List`, `Set` or `Bag` of `Character`, the following will work:

```
LazyIterable<Character> lazyIterable = abc.asLazy().collect(Character::valueOf);
List<Character> list = lazyIterable.toList();
Set<Character> set = lazyIterable.toSet();
Bag<Character> set = lazyIterable.toBag();
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 1):

**Using Java 8 - Stream Funtion:**

**Converting A String into Character List:**

```
ArrayList<Character> characterList =  givenStringVariable
                                                         .chars()
                                                         .mapToObj(c-> (char)c)
                                                         .collect(collectors.toList());
```

**Converting A Character List into String:**

```
 String givenStringVariable =  characterList
                                            .stream()
                                            .map(String::valueOf)
                                            .collect(Collectors.joining())
```

Answer (score 0):

IntStream can be used to access each character and add them to the list.

```
String str = "abc";
List<Character> charList = new ArrayList<>();
IntStream.range(0,str.length()).forEach(i -> charList.add(str.charAt(i)));
```

Answer (score 0):

**To get a list of Characters / Strings -**

```
List<String> stringsOfCharacters = string.chars().
                                   mapToObj(i -> (char)i).
                                   map(c -> c.toString()).
                                   collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

We can convert `List` of `String` into `Set` of characters as below.

```
Set<Character> charSet = new HashSet<>();
List<String> strList = List.of("abc", "cde", "def", "afc");
strList.forEach(str -> {
                charSet.addAll(str.chars()
                                  .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
                                  .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
            });
```

Output will be something like this.

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f]
```