# Why doesn't Java have a BooleanStream?

Tags: java, boolean, java-8, java-stream

Java 8 introduced streams. There are three streams for primitives (IntStream (of `int`), LongStream (of `long`), DoubleStream (of `double`)) and a generic Stream for objects.

I assume that's there's no FloatStream, CharStream, ByteStream, or ShortStream because these are all "subtypes" of existing streams. That is, a stream of `short` can have each element easily converted to `int`.

But why is there no `BooleanStream`?

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant, but internally the JVM represents `boolean`s the same way it represents `byte`s. Perhaps they expected you to use `IntStream`?

Comment: What would a use case for such stream?

Comment: @templatetypedef, except you can promote a `byte` value to `int` because the boolean data type (set of values) is a proper subset of the int data type.  In the Java language, unlike certain other languages I know, the boolean type, {`true`, `false`}, is disjoint from the int type.

Comment: @PM77-1 I haven't learned streams yet, so I may be way off base here, but bit strings are not unusual in computer science (Huffman codes, for example).

Comment: @PM77-1 e.g. to use `collect()` to _xor_ all the values or find the number of `true` values. Also, to convert another stream to an array of booleans.

Comment: For my take on this issue see [my answer to a different question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22497858/1441122). Basically it's in agreement with Brian Goetz's rationale, just stated differently.

Comment: But basically if you really wanted a `BooleanStream` you could use an `IntStream` with values 0 or 1. Of course you could also pack 32 booleans into an `int` or 64 into a `long` if you wanted to improve space efficiency.

Comment: @Ypnypn: “find the number of `true` values”: [`bitSet.stream().count()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#stream--). Of course, `bitSet.cardinality()` would do as well. Btw. there is nothing what a `BooleanStream` could do what a `Stream<Boolean>` can’t. For collecting into a `boolean[]` you would just need a specialized `Collector`.