# How to convert a String to a Java 8 Stream of Characters?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435833/why-is-string-chars-a-stream-of-ints-in-java-8) about getting a java.util.streams.IntStream from a java String but I have not found this method now that I'm using Java 8.

Correction: As you guys pointed, I was using Java 7. Now the method `chars()` is there. But the question still applies:

How can I get a `Stream<Character>` from a String?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I was going to point you to [my earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22497858/1441122) on this topic but it turns out that you've already linked to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435833/why-is-string-chars-a-stream-of-ints-in-java-8). The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22436638/1441122) also provides useful information.

If you want `char` values, you can use the `IntStream` returned by `String.chars()` and cast the `int` values to `char` without loss of information. The other answers explained why there's no `CharStream` primitive specialization for the `Stream` class.

If you really want boxed `Character` objects, then use `mapToObj()` to convert from `IntStream` to a stream of reference type. Within `mapToObj()`, cast the `int` value to `char`. Since an object is expected as a return value here, the `char` will be autoboxed into a `Character`. This results in `Stream<Character>`. For example,

```
Stream<Character> sch = "abc".chars().mapToObj(i -> (char)i);
sch.forEach(ch -> System.out.printf("%c %s%n", ch, ch.getClass().getName()));

a java.lang.Character
b java.lang.Character
c java.lang.Character
```

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure that you are using JDK 8. This method located in CharSequence interface, implemented by String.

This snippet works fine:

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class CharsSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s =  "123";
        IntStream chars = s.chars();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I got gradle to use Java 7. But how can I get a Stream<Character> from a String?

Comment: @ElderMael Are you using Java 7 or Java 8? These methods and types are new to Java 8.

Answer (score 2):

I'm late with another approach using `Pattern` method: `splitAsStream()`

`String test = "Lobgasex loga nepe co so x";`

```
List<Character> chars = Pattern.compile("").splitAsStream(test)
    .map(i -> i.charAt(0))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```