# In java how do you see if a number ONLY contains 1,2,3?

Tags: java

I have a java problem in which I have to see if a 9 digit number contains ONLY 1,2,3 - and also has the same number of 1 as 2 as 3 and vice versa.

For example:

- 123231312 = true
- 111111111 = false
- 112731923 = false

Comment: Would 222333111 be ok?

Comment: if any of the solutions solved your problem, don't forget to mark it as the answer.

Comment: I wonder why so many people give OP direct answer given OP have not even shown a bit of effort of solving it

Answer (score 0):

```
 private boolean onlyContainsOneTwoAndThree(int number) {
    char[] digitsFromNumber = String.valueOf(number).toCharArray(); // convert to char[] for easier manipulation.
    int oneCounter = 0;
    int twoCounter = 0;
    int threeCounter = 0;

    for (char digit : digitsFromNumber) {
        switch (digit) {
            case '1':
                oneCounter++;
                break;
            case '2':
                twoCounter++;
                break;
            case '3':
                threeCounter++;
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
    if ((oneCounter == twoCounter) && (twoCounter == threeCounter)) {
        return true; // return true only when 1,2 and 3 appear exactly the same number of times.
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean correct(String input) {
    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    char[] charArray = input.toCharArray();

    for (char num : charArray) {
        Integer count = map.get(num);
        if (count == null) {
            count = 0;
        }
        map.put(num, count.intValue() + 1);
    }

    Integer val = map.get('1');
    if (val != null && val == map.get('2') && val == map.get('3') &&
        map.size() == 3) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: you don't need maps, you can just have counters (int). Less memory, more efficient.

Comment: size() isn't a method for Integer, see line 15 (above the return)

Comment: @David Sorry meant `map.size()` ... I was on a cell phone at the time :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isGood(String input) {
     return input.length() == 9 && 2D == input.chars()
                                            .parallel()
                                            .mapToObj(i -> (char)i)
                                            .map(Character::getNumericValue)
                                            .map(number -> number >= 1 && number <= 3 ? number : Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                                            .mapToInt(number -> number).average().orElse(-1);
}
```

Comment: where did you find the method 'chars()'?

Comment: After the filter, you will just have 1,2 and 3, that doesn't imply that the input string did not have other numbers (4,5,6 etc.). Try testing the code before posting.

Comment: String.chars is available with Java 8 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435833/why-is-string-chars-a-stream-of-ints-in-java-8

Comment: I don't think you know what filter means? Also the chars method is from the CharSequence interface. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#chars

Comment: dude, just try to run the method you suggested, with 123456789 as input.

Comment: and filter just returns the stream of elements which satisfy the condition, which doesn't imply that other digits are not present in the input string.

Comment: removed the filter. whoops.

Answer (score -1):

```
String s = Integer.toString(number);
System.out.println(s.contains("1") && s.contains("2") && s.contains("3"));
```

Comment: The OP specifically mentioned that `112731923 = BAD`, but your code would pass it, since it contains a 1, 2, and a 3.  Please test your code before posting it.