# Convert a Object[] of booleans to a boolean[] using streams

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream

I can do the conversion with code like this:

```
Object[] array = (Object[]) message.get(key);
boolean[] result = new boolean[array.length];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    result[i] = (boolean) array[i];
}
```

But, I was think that is possible to do the same conversion using Java 8 streams. I start to code something like this:

```
boolean[] =  Arrays.stream(array)
                   .map(Boolean.class::cast)
                   .map(Boolean::booleanValue)
                   .toArray()
```

But this code doesn't work. Compiler says

```
incompatible types: java.lang.Object[] cannot be converted to boolean[]
```

I'm trying to understand what is the problem with the code. I think that `map(Boolean::booleanValue)` would return a stream of boolean values I can collect with `toArray`.

Comment: This will not work because `Object[]` and `boolean[]` are types in Java that are not convertible, so actually `Object[] = boolean[]` will not work either.

Comment: `.toArray()` here is generic, so `Object[]` is the best you can achieve. You may write your own collector to return `boolean[]`.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou You can however use `toArray(IntFunction<A[]> generator)` to return a typed array. I added an answer as an example.

Comment: There's a related discussion here, for why the primitive streams are limited to only certain types: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435833/why-is-string-chars-a-stream-of-ints-in-java-8 (Why e.g. no `CharStream`/`BooleanStream`/etc. like there is `IntStream`.)

Answer (score 22):

No, because `map(Boolean::booleanValue)` expands to

```
map((Boolean value) -> (Boolean)value.booleanValue());
```

(note the autoboxing inserted by the compiler, because the function passed to `map()` has to return an `Object`, not a `boolean`)

This is why the Java8 streams include a whole bunch of specialized classes (`IntStream`, `LongStream`, and `DoubleStream`). Sadly, there is no specialized stream class for `boolean`.

Answer (score 12):

The only streams of primitive type are `IntStream`, `LongStream` and `DoubleStream`. In particular there is no `BooleanStream` and there is no idiomatic way to convert a `Stream<Boolean>` to a `boolean[]`.

If you need this functionality frequently you can use a utility class like this:

```
public final class BooleanUtils {

    private BooleanUtils() {}

    public static boolean[] listToArray(List<Boolean> list) {
        int length = list.size();
        boolean[] arr = new boolean[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            arr[i] = list.get(i);
        return arr;
    }

    public static final Collector<Boolean, ?, boolean[]> TO_BOOLEAN_ARRAY
         = Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), BooleanUtils::listToArray);
}
```

Then, given a `Stream<Boolean>`, you will be able to do:

```
boolean[] arr = stream.collect(BooleanUtils.TO_BOOLEAN_ARRAY);
```

Answer (score 8):

If you're not opposed to the idea of getting a list instead, you can simply perform `collect` as your terminal action:

```
final List<Boolean> boolList = Arrays.stream(array)
                                     .map(Boolean.class::cast)
                                     .map(Boolean::booleanValue)
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The stream as defined here is only capable of producing an `Object[]` if you attempt to collect it into an array.  Using a list will at least allow you to maintain the type you want to convert it into.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can't the OP convert the list into a boolean array afterwards if they really wanted to?

Comment: @JeelShah:  Yes, but they would be able to get a `Boolean[]`, not a `boolean[]`.  If the OP wanted the `boolean[]` they'd have to do a bit more work.

Comment: Ahhh okay. Thanks for the additional info!

Answer (score 4):

I think it is worth noting too that there is a `toArray(IntFunction<A[]> generator)` that will at least allow you to have a final result of `Boolean[]` which is closer to what you wanted.

```
Boolean[] boolArray =  Arrays.stream(array)
               .map(Boolean.class::cast)
               .toArray(Boolean[]::new);
```

Answer (score 4):

In my free [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/) library there's a collector [`toBooleanArray`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/MoreCollectors.html#toBooleanArray-java.util.function.Predicate-) which creates a primitive boolean array:

```
boolean[] result = Arrays.stream(array)
                         .collect(MoreCollectors.toBooleanArray(obj -> (boolean)obj));
```

If you don't like using third-party library you can implement such collector by yourself:

```
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, boolean[]> toBooleanArray(Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
    class Acc {
        BitSet bs = new BitSet();
        int count = 0;
    }
    return Collector.of(Acc::new, (acc, t) -> acc.bs.set(acc.count++, predicate.test(t)),
            (acc1, acc2) -> {
                acc2.bs.stream().forEach(i -> acc1.bs.set(i + acc1.count));
                acc1.count += acc2.count;
                return acc1;
            }, acc -> {
                boolean[] res = new boolean[acc.count];
                acc.bs.stream().forEach(i -> res[i] = true);
                return res;
            });
}
```

It works well for sequential and parallel streams and quite memory-friendly.

Answer (score 3):

Java primitive types aren't reference types, so you can't do directly convert `Boolean` to `boolean` ([autoboxing and unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) were added to the language in Java 1.5 and don't work with arrays of wrapper types to the primitive types). However, you could use an [`IntStream.range(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-) like

```
boolean[] result = new boolean[array.length];
IntStream.range(0, array.length).forEach(x -> result[x] = (boolean) array[x]);
```