# how to create boolean array from stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of `Class1`, which has a method `isAvailable()` which returns a boolean.

I am trying to create an array of boolean from this.

So far I have tried the below:

```
List<Class1> class1List;
boolean[] isAvailableArray =  class1List.stream()
                                        .map(e -> e.isAvailable())
                                        .toArray();
```

However this is throwing  a ***can't convert from `Object[]` to `boolean[]`*** error.

What is the reason for this.

Comment: tried that and no that still does not work

Comment: Then i expect you would need to use the Wrapper classes Boolean. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36507509/16034206) is somewhat similar. I think its because streams dont work with primitives?

Comment: The stream in your code and in general is only capable of producing an Object[] if you attempt to collect it into an array. Using a list will at least allow you to maintain the type you want to convert it into.

Comment: `Boolean[] isAvailableArray =  class1List.stream().map(e -> e.isAvailable()).toArray(Boolean[]::new);`

Comment: Why do you even want a `boolean[]`? It’s very likely that whatever you want to do with the boolean array afterwards, can be done directly or at least, with an alternative way not requiring the boolean array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a Object\[\] of booleans to a boolean\[\] using streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36507509/convert-a-object-of-booleans-to-a-boolean-using-streams)

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the following example, the stream handles the primitive boolean values correctly (it creates Boolean objects). However, when `toArray` is used without a `generator` param (constructor), it falls back to an `Object` array.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

public class BooleanStream {
    public static class SomeClass {
        public boolean isAvailable() {
            return true;
        }
    }
    @Test
    public void testBoolean() {
        List<ByteArray.SomeClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
        ByteArray.SomeClass someClass = new ByteArray.SomeClass();
        list.add(someClass);

        Object[] isAvailableArray = list.stream().map(e -> e.isAvailable()).toArray();
        assertTrue(isAvailableArray[0] instanceof Boolean);
    }
}
```

As [experiment-unit-1998x](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16034206/experiment-unit-1998x) pointed out, the best solution is probably the generator param.