# Java 8: removing spaces and duplicated character from string not working with stream api

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I want to remove duplicated characters and spaces with java 8 streams api but my code is not working :

```
Stream.of(sentence.toCharArray()).flatMap(x->Character.valueOf(x)).
    distinct().sorted().forEach(System.out::print);
```

Please suggest a way use stream api for this.

Comment: This site is not a coding service. The way you contstruct your stream is not correct, try this http://www.baeldung.com/java-string-to-stream.

Comment: @Michal Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
sentence.chars()
   .mapToObj(i -> (char)i)
   .distinct()
   .filter(x -> x != ' ')
   .sorted()
   .forEach(System.out::print);
```

Just a word of caution `.chars()` returns a `IntStream` and hence you need to cast it to `char`. You can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435833/why-is-string-chars-a-stream-of-ints-in-java-8) for further details on why String.chars() returns a IntStream

Comment: Thanks @pvpkiran.

Comment: instead of `filter(x -> x != ' ')` is better to use `filter(c -> ! Character.isWhitespace(c))`

Comment: I’d move the `.mapToObj(i -> (char)i)` as far to the end as possible. Since here, all intermediate operations work (better) with `int` values, the best place would be right before the `.forEach(System.out::print)`, the only operation where it matters. Or you use `.forEach(i -> System.out.print((char)i))`, then you don’t need to box to `Character` at all. You may get another performance benefit from using `sentence.chars() .sorted().distinct() .filter(x -> x != ' ') .forEach(i -> System.out.print((char)i))`, as `.distinct()` is capable of utilizing the sorted nature of the incoming data.

Answer (score 2):

[`Stream#of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of(T...)) does not support primitive char arrays. Therefore you're getting a `Stream<char[]>`. It would be better to use [`CharSequence#chars`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#chars()).

```
sentence.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).distinct().sorted().forEach(Sytem.out::print);
```