# Cannot resolve method Character::hashCode in a Java stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

In my example, I try to create an ASCII table from a sequence of characters. I managed to do it with a `List` of strings but failed with an array of chars.

I get an error that `Character::hashCode` cannot be resolved in `Collectors.toMap()`.

```
Error:(26, 17) java: method collect in interface java.util.stream.IntStream cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.util.function.Supplier<R>,java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer<R>,java.util.function.BiConsumer<R,R>
  found: java.util.stream.Collector<java.lang.Object,capture#1 of ?,java.util.Map<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object>>
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
    (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
Error:(26, 42) java: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) T,K,U,T
    (argument mismatch; invalid method reference
      incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to char)
```

Is there a way to do it?

```
public class JavaCollectToMapEx2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // list of ASCII characters
        var chars = List.of("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f",
                "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n",
                "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v",
                "w", "x", "y", "z");

//      CharSequence chars2 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        char[] letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();

        // Map to represent ASCII character table
        Map<Integer, String> asciiMap = chars.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(String::hashCode, Function.identity()));

        Map<Integer, Character> asciiMap2 = CharBuffer.wrap(letters).chars() 
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Character::hashCode, Function.identity()));

        System.out.println(asciiMap);
        System.out.println(asciiMap2);
    }
}
```

Comment: and no error message???

Comment: I have added the full error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`.chars()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/CharSequence.html#chars()) is giving you an `IntStream`, which is a stream of primitive `int`, and not a stream of characters ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22436638/862594)). This is why no method references on `Character` will work.

To achieve what you're looking for, you'll need a `Stream<Character>` first:

```
Map<Integer, Character> asciiMap2 = CharBuffer.wrap(letters)
        .chars()
        .mapToObj(e -> (char) e)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.hashCode(), Function.identity()));
```

Now, you still have the issue of using a method reference for getting the hash code. You can't use `Character::hashCode` because it's ambiguous as to which method you want, as there are two that are possible:

1. The override of Object#hashCode,
2. The static method `int hashCode(char value)`

You can see from this code, that both satisfy the first argument to `toMap()`:

```
Function<Character, Integer> f1 = e -> Character.hashCode(e);
Function<Character, Integer> f2 = e -> e.hashCode();
```

To resolve this, you can use `Object::hashCode` for the non-static method call.

Comment: The actual problem, regarding the posted compiler error, was that `IntStream` doesn't have a `collect(Collector)` method. An alternative would have been `CharBuffer.wrap(letters) .chars() .boxed() .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), e -> (char)e));`

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using the method `collect()` after [`CharBuffer::chars`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html#chars--) which returns [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html), the only collecting method you can use is [`IntStream::collect(Supplier<R> supplier, ObjIntConsumer<R> accumulator,  BiConsumer<R,R> combiner)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) taking 3 parameters.

If you wish to use one-parameter collecting method, place [`IntStream::boxed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed--) before it to return `Stream<Integer>`. Then the method `Character::hashCode` becomes ambiguous and the lambda expression cannot be used:

- [`hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#hashCode--)
- [`hashCode(char value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#hashCode-char-)

To avoid this, simply use a better method [`mapToObj`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapToObj-java.util.function.IntFunction-) to cast to `char` directly without need of boxing and then use `Object::hashCode` inherited from the `Object:

```
Map<Integer, Character> asciiMap2 = CharBuffer.wrap(letters).chars()
    .mapToObj(ch -> (char) ch)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Object::hashCode, Function.identity()));
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to map the `IntStream` to a `Stream<Character>`. But after that you can not use the Method reference `Character::hashCode` because it is ambiguous (object level and class level):

```
Map<Integer, Character> asciiMap2 = CharBuffer.wrap(letters).chars()
        .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> Character.hashCode(i), Function.identity()));
```

Alternatively you can just use `Object::hashCode` instead of `i -> Character.hashCode(i)` because the `Character` class overrides it's `hashCode()` method using `Character.hashCode()`:

```
public final class Character ... {
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Character.hashCode(value);
    }
}
```

So finally you can just use this:

```
Map<Integer, Character> asciiMap2 = CharBuffer.wrap(letters).chars()
        .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Object::hashCode, Function.identity()));
```