# How to convert a string to a sequence of characters using stream API

Tags: java

Can the following code be converted to stream? I have tried this a lot of times but I kind of got stuck in someplace.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

while(sc.hasNext()) {
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    line.chars().forEach(i -> System.out.println((char)i));
}

sc.close();
```

Comment: But you alraedy use a Stream there. I don't get which part do you want to convert.

Comment: For me this works fine?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is String.chars() a stream of ints in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435833/why-is-string-chars-a-stream-of-ints-in-java-8)

Comment: I know chars return IntStream but I want to replace while loop as well

Comment: Did you search before posting this question, in case of stream, this is basic example available in internet.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Exactly.. hahaha

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I think the votes came in because expectation was to conver `Scanner` next elements to stream which kind of looks hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a `Spliterator` from `Scanner` which can then be passed to [`StreamSupport#stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html#stream-java.util.Spliterator-boolean-) to create an `IntStream`. Here is an example:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

try ( IntStream is = StreamSupport.stream(
            Spliterators.spliterator(sc, Long.MAX_VALUE, Spliterator.ORDERED), false)
        .onClose(sc::close)
        .flatMapToInt(s -> s.chars()); ) {
    is.forEach(i -> System.out.println((char) i));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

while(sc.hasNext()) {
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    Arrays.stream(line.split(""))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}

sc.close()
```