# Why do I have to sync a bidirectional relationship even with CascadeType.PERSIST using Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, database, hibernate, jpa

Here is an example code demonstrating the issue:

The Meal Entity:

```java
@Entity
public class Meal {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "meal", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  private Collection<Food> foods;

  public Meal() {
    foods = new HashSet<>();
  }

  public Collection<Food> getFoods() {
    return foods;
  }

  public void addFood(Food food) {
    foods.add(food);
    // without this the `meal_id` column is null
    food.setMeal(this);
  }
}
```

The Food Entity:

```java
@Entity
public class Food {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long id;

  @ManyToOne
  private Meal meal;

  public long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public Meal getMeal() {
    return meal;
  }

  public void setMeal(Meal meal) {
    this.meal = meal;
  }
}
```

And here is the code that creates and saves the entities:

```java
Meal meal = new Meal();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  meal.addFood(new Food());
}

mealRepository.save(meal);
```

Both the Meal and the Food entities are persisted thanks to the `CascadeType.PERSIST`, but the `meal_id` column stays null if I don't explicitly set the `meal` field to the Meal entity.

This is not the behavior I'd expect, and I'm wondering why isn't this automatically done for me.

Comment: A lot of things aren't automatically done for you, so you just had the wrong expectation. Why  would it be done automatically since `foods.add(food);` isn't done automatically? The programmer is ultimately responsible for the working of the program, so reading the documentation is essential in tricky cases like bi-directional mappings.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it works as designed.

Comment: @Kayaman "works as designed" is not really an answer when the question is why. I understand you don't know the answer, perhaps others will.

Comment: @Kayaman I suggest you to look into DX (Developer Experience). Great software tools for developers work as expected most of the time.
A developer at one point made a design decision and I'm curios what lead to that decision, and that's my question is all about.

Comment: I've got over two decades of "DX" with Java, so don't patronize me. You can send an email to Gavin King, the original author of Hibernate, and ask if it was him alone that made a decision, or whether it even was a decision as you assume. These kinds of questions are bad (and usually closed) because most design decisions aren't known to SO users, although you may find them from the projects' internal mailing lists or bugtrackers.

Comment: In fact you can find plenty of explanation for design decisions on SO, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435833/why-is-string-chars-a-stream-of-ints-in-java-8
I usually enjoy reading these.

Comment: In some lucky cases yes, if you manage to get an authoritative answer from someone like Stuart Marks or Brian Goetz. However that's not the general case, and the good questions tend to be old. I enjoy reading experts' answers too. I just wish there were more of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```java
@Entity
public class Meal {


  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "meal", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  private Collection<Food> foods;

}
```

The `mappedBy` here means that the value of `meal` field in `Food` is used to provide the value for the corresponding database column that link between `Food` and `Meal` (i.e. `meal_id` column in `Food` table). So if you do not set it, it will always remain NULL.

On the other hand, without `mappedBy` means that the value of the `foods` field in `Meal` is used to provide the value for `meal_id` column. The reason of manually syncing them is just to have a consistent OOP model to work with.

`CascadeType.PERSIST` is nothing to do with setting the value of the entity. It will never update the value of the entities for you. What it helps is to automatically calling some `entityManager` methods on the related entities. Without it, you have to call the following to save all Food and Meal:

```java
entityManager.persist(meal);
entityManager.persist(food1);
entityManager.persist(food2);
......
entityManager.persist(foodN);
```

With it , you just need to call

```java
entityManager.persist(meal);
```

and the rest of `entityManager.persist(foodN)` will be 'cascaded' to call automatically.

So in term of spring-data-jpa , instead of calling

```java
mealRepository.save(meal);
foodRepository.persist(food1);
foodRepository.persist(food2);
......
foodRepository.persist(foodN);
```

You just need to call

```java
mealRepository.save(meal);
```