# How can i convert String to Character Stream using streamAPI?

Tags: java, string, java-stream, character

```
String st = "FindCaptialWords";
```

Can we convert above string to character stream using StreamApi?

Comment: `st.chars()` which gives you an `IntStream` which is equivalent to what a character stream is (there is no `CharStream` in Java).

Comment: or  Stream.of(st.toCharArray())

Comment: @DmitriiBykov It won't work _as intended_ returning a single-element stream of `char[]` which is kind of useless.

Comment: @Olivier Java 8, along with the rest of the Stream API. [Design decisions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22435833/2541560) behind it.

Answer (score 0):

I just use

```java
Stream<Character> foo = st.chars().mapToObj(c -> Character.valueOf((char) c));
```

though a stream of codepoints becomes much more useful than a stream of `chars` as soon as you need to deal with text outside of the BMP since a single `char`/`Character` can't hold those values, and so you're back to working with an `IntStream` as returned by `st.codePoints()`.