# The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) char[], int

Tags: java, string, char

```
String x = "abcd";

Arrays.asList(x.toCharArray()).forEach(y -> System.out.println(y + 1));
// this line is giving an error that + operator is undefined for char[] and int.

Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2}).forEach(y -> {System.out.println(y + 1);});
// for integer it is working fine.
```

When we use `+` operator for doing something like this `'a' + 1` we get 98 because ASCII value of a is 97.
So why it is not working with char array in the above case.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: `Arrays.asList(x.toCharArray())` will return you a `List<char[]>` and not a `List<char>` or `List<Character>`

Comment: You misunderstand what `Arrays.asList(x.toCharArray())` does. It creates a stream with one element: the char array. It does not create a stream of the individual characters.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319775/java-collections-convert-a-string-to-a-list-of-characters

Answer (score 3):

`Arrays.asList` consider `x.toCharArray()` as an object because `x.toCharArray()` return `char[]`, so it is considers as one element, and you can't make `char[] + int`, to solve this you can use `x.chars()` :

```
x.chars().forEach(y -> System.out.println(y + 1));
```

Comment: or simply `for(char y : x.toCharArray()) { System.out.println(y + 1); }`

Comment: @Lino I agree, but the OP use forEach :)