# Converting ArrayList of Characters to a String?

Tags: java, string, collections

How to convert an `ArrayList<Character>` to a `String` in Java?

The `List.toString` method returns it as `[a,b,c]` string - I want to get rid of the brackets (etcetera) and store it as `abc`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can iterate through the list and create the string.

```
String getStringRepresentation(ArrayList<Character> list)
{    
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(list.size());
    for(Character ch: list)
    {
        builder.append(ch);
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Setting the capacity of the `StringBuilder` to the list size is an important optimization.  If you don't do this, some of the `append` calls may trigger an internal resize of the builder.

As an aside, `toString()` returns a human-readable format of the ArrayList's contents. It is not worth the time to filter out the unnecessary characters from it. It's implementation could change tomorrow, and you will have to rewrite your filtering code.

Comment: What is the advantage of using StringBuilder and than toString method instead of simply use String class?

Comment: @Line - it is more efficient to use a `StringBuilder`.  Appending `N` characters using naive string concatenation is `O(N^2)`.  And if you are talking about using `ArrayList.toString()` and filtering, the filtering step is another `O(N)` pass over the string ... compared with single pass approach ^^^.

Answer (score 30):

Here a possible one-line solution using Java8 streams.

a) List of Character objects to String :

```
String str = chars.stream()
                  .map(e->e.toString())
                  .reduce((acc, e) -> acc  + e)
                  .get();
```

b) array of chars (char[] chars)

```
String str = Stream.of(chars)
                   .map(e->new String(e))
                   .reduce((acc, e) -> acc  + e)
                   .get();
```

***UPDATE*** (following comment below):

a) List of Character objects to String :

```
String str = chars.stream()
                  .map(e->e.toString())
                  .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

b) array of chars (char[] chars)

```
String str = Stream.of(chars)
                   .map(e->new String(e))
                   .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

---

Note that the `map(e->e.toString())` step in the above solutions will create a temporary string for each character in the list.  The strings immediately become garbage.  So, if the performance of the conversion is a relevant concern, you should consider using the [`StringBuilder` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6324852/139985) instead.

Comment: In my case i have to typecast
String str = (String)(chars.stream().map(e->e.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining()));

Answer (score 2):

How about this, Building the list

```
List<Character> charsList = new ArrayList<Character>();
charsList.add('h');
charsList.add('e');
charsList.add('l');
charsList.add('l');
charsList.add('o');
```

**Actual code to get String from List of Character:**

```
String word= new String();
for(char c:charsList){
word= word+ c; 
}
System.out.println(word);
```

Still learning if there is a misake point out.

Comment: No mistake, but using a StringBuilder is way more efficient than String contatenation

Comment: This is an `O(N^2)` solution because each string concatenation is copying the entire string ... so far.  Better solutions are `O(N)`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a following list:

```
final ArrayList<Character> charsList = new ArrayList<Character>();
charsList.add('h');
charsList.add('e');
charsList.add('l');
charsList.add('l');
charsList.add('o');
```

This will yield *`hello`* (I am using [`org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html) helper class):

```
final Character[] charactersArray =
    charsList.toArray(new Character[charsList.size()]);
final char[] charsArray = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(charactersArray);
System.out.println(String.valueOf(charsArray));
```

Comment: why use a third-party library when the standard library will suffice?

Comment: Is there a standard method that does the same thing as `ArrayUtils#toPrimitive`? I know the problem can be solved with different approaches, I am asking about this specific method which I have chosen to avoid explicit loop. Besides, I can't imagine no `commons-lang` on CLASSPATH nowadays...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using toString() and RegExp without any loops and streams:

`List<Character> list = Arrays.asList('a', 'b', 'c');
String s = list.toString().replaceAll("[,\\s\\[\\]]", "");`

Comment: This is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 1):

Using `join` of a `Joiner` class:

```
// create character list and initialize 
List<Character> arr = Arrays.asList('a', 'b', 'c');   
String str = Joiner.on("").join(arr);
System.out.println(str);
```

Use `toString` then remove `, and spaces`

```
import com.google.common.base.Joiner; 

....
<Character> arr = Arrays.asList('h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'); 
// remove [] and spaces 
String str = arr.toString() 
          .substring(1, 3 * str.size() - 1) //3 bcs of commas ,
          .replaceAll(", ", ""); 
System.out.println(str);
```

Or by using streams:

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors; 
...
// using collect and joining() method 
String str =  arr.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Answer (score 0):

Many solutions available. You can iterate over the chars and append to a StringBuilder, then when finished appending, call .toString on the StringBuilder.

Or use something like commons-lang StringUtils.join from the apache commons-lang project.

Answer (score 0):

a tiny complement to @waggledans 's answer

**a) List of Character objects to String :**

```
String str = chars.stream().map(e->e.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining());
```

which `e->e.toString()` can be replaced by `Object::toString`

```
String str = chars.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Answer (score -1):

I consider this an easy and smart way

```
 // given list containing the chars
 List<Character> arr = Arrays.asList('a', 'b', 'c'); 
 
//convert list to string
 String output = arr.toString().replaceAll("[ ,]","")
                       .substring(1, tmpArr.length()-1);
```

**Explanation:**

```
// convert to string.
String str = arr.toString(); // result is "[a ,b ,c]"

// get rid of the start and the end char i.e '[' & ']'
str = str.substring(1, tmpArr.length()-1);  //result is "a ,b ,c"

// replace <space> and ','
str = str.replaceAll(" ,","") "ABC"
```

Comment: Doesn’t work if any characters are `,` or space.

Answer (score -2):

I would say :

```
public String arayListToString(ArrayList arrayList){

StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();

for(String s : arrayList){
   b.append(s);
   b.append(",");
}

return b.toString();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
 private void countChar() throws IOException {
    HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();
    List list = new ArrayList();
    list = "aammit".chars().mapToObj(r -> (char) r).collect(Collectors.toList());
    list.stream().forEach(e -> {
        hashMap.computeIfPresent(e, (K, V) -> (int) V + 1);
        hashMap.computeIfAbsent(e, (V) -> 1);
    });

    System.out.println(hashMap);

}
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question