# Convert ArrayList <Characters> into a String

Tags: java, string, arraylist

Is there a simple way of converting an ArrayList that contains only characters into a string? So say we have

```
ArrayList<Character> arrayListChar = new ArrayList<Character>();
arrayListChar.add(a);
arrayListChar.add(b);
arrayListChar.add(c);
```

So the array list contains a, b, and c. Ideally what I'd want to  do is turn that into a String "abc".

Comment: Possible duplicate of question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6324826/601409

Comment: even better answers were provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523871/best-way-to-concatenate-list-of-string-objects It's about concatenating list of Strings, but close.

Answer (score 3):

```
Iterator<Character> it = arrayListChar.iterator();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

while(it.hasNext()) {
    sb.append(it.next());
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Apache Common Lang's](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) StringUtils class. It has a `join()` function like you find in PHP.

Then the code:

```
StringUtils.join(arrayListChar, "")
```

would generate:

```
abc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    int size = list.size();
    char[] chars = new char[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (list.size() != size) {
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        }
        chars[i] = list.get(i);
    }
    String s = new String(chars);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regex magic:

```
String result = list.toString().replaceAll(", |\\[|\\]", "");
```

Get the String representation of the list, which is

```
[a, b, c]
```

and then remove the strings `"[", "]", and ", "`.

Answer (score 0):

You can override it's `toString` method and implement the `String` formatting therein.

Answer (score 0):

Override toString method of ArrayList or the better to extend the ArrayList class so that you may use old ArrayList toString() somewhere else in the code

Answer (score 0):

```
    String s = "";
    for(Character i : arrayListChar)
           s += i;
```

EDIT - as pointed out already, you should only use code like this if the number of strings to concatenate is small.

Comment: String are immutable, you will create a new string for every concatenation. Very bad use of memory. Try using a StringBuilder instead.