# .toArray from ArrayList to Array convertion, data type confusion

Tags: java, arraylist, casting, processing, toarray

I have confused myself with typecasting with this problem.

I have an `ArrayList` of chars that I want to convert into a String—an array of chars. So it goes something like this:

```
ArrayList<Character> message = new ArrayList<Character>();
String stringMessage = new String;
stringMessage = message.toArray(stringMessage);
```

Now the error that is given is:

> "Syntax error, maybe a missing semicolon?"

which isn't very helpful.

Is there something wrong with how I cast this? Is it not possible to convert an `ArrayList` of characters into a `String`?

Comment: `new String` <-- error here. And `message.toArray()` will only accept an array as an argument, which `stringMessage` is not.

Comment: Even if `toArray` accepted `String` as argument (It doesn't), it still returns an array

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting ArrayList of Characters to a String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324826/converting-arraylist-of-characters-to-a-string)

Comment: First error can be resolved by simply writing `String stringMessage;`. But what are you really trying to do? The third line doesn't make sense.

Comment: To clearify: I'm using ArrayList as it has some advantages when handeling the data during the program, but for functions that can only handle the String object I need to do this conversion. Thank you all for the quick replies, fge's code solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
final CharBuffer buf = CharBuffer.allocate(message.size());
for (final Character c: message)
    buf.put(c.charValue());
stringMessage = new String(buf.array());
```

You cannot use `.toArray()` directly since it would return a `Character[]`, not a `char[]`, and there is no `String` constructor accepting a `Character[]` as an argument...