# Print all characters from ArrayList after each other

Tags: java

I have this ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Character> wrongLetters;
```

And this syso

```
System.out.println("Number of errors: " + wrongLetters.size() + " (" +  String.join("", String.valueOf(wrongLetters)) + ")");
```

It now prints like this

```
Number of errors: 9 ([X, M, S, K, B, Q, L, I, U])
```

**But how can I make it like this**

```
Number of errors: 9 (XMSKBQLIU)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 8 or later:

```
final String result = wrongLetters.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining());
System.out.println("Number of errors: " + wrongLetters.size() + " (" +  result + ")");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use wrongLetters.forEach(System.out::print); in Java 8

Answer (score 0):

Stupid answer (just remove non-alphanumerics):

```
System.out.println("Number of errors: " + wrongLetters.size() + " (" + String.join("", String.valueOf(wrongLetters).replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", ""))+ ")");
```

One more for Java 8+:

```
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner("");
    wrongLetters.stream().forEach(err -> joiner.add(String.valueOf(err)));
    System.out.println("Number of errors: " + wrongLetters.size() + " (" + joiner + ")");
```

No Java 8 (using StringBuilder):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(" (");
    for (Character character : wrongLetters) {
        sb.append(character);
    }
    sb.append(")");
    System.out.println("Number of errors: " + wrongLetters.size() + sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by this way using Java 8

```
System.out.println(wrongLetters.stream().map(x -> x.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining()));
```

Comment: expression `.map(x -> x.toString())` could be replaced with method reference to the Object class like `map(Object::toString)`.

Comment: Hey @dbl I'm still learning Java 8. Thanks for the comment will learn from this too.

Answer (score 0):

String.valueOf(wrongLetters) calls toString() on array of characters thats why it look likt this. Join is called only for one String here **[X, M, S, K, B, Q, L, I, U]**.
You have to change ArrayList to String. Check this -> [Converting ArrayList of Characters to a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324826/converting-arraylist-of-characters-to-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

make a string from the arraylist of the characters

```
String str = "";
for (Character c : wrongLetters) {
    str += c;
}
```

then :

```
System.out.println("Number of errors: " + wrongLetters.size() + " (" +  String.join("", str) + ")");
```

or make a string builder :

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder= new StringBuilder(wrongLetters.size());

    for (Character c : wrongLetters) {
      stringBuilder.append(c);
    }
```

then:

```
       System.out.println("Number of errors: " + wrongLetters.size() + " (" +  String.join("", stringBuilder.toString()) + ")");
```