# how to stop this infinite loop in java?

Tags: java

So I'm supposed to make a "scramble" game that asks the user for a word, then the program scrambles that word for the second user to guess.

```
import java.util.*;

class scrabble {
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a word: ");
    String abc = input.nextLine();

    String scrambled = "";
    Random randGen = new Random();

    while(scrambled.length() != abc.length())
    {
       char rand = abc.charAt(randGen.nextInt(abc.length()));
       if(!scrambled.contains("" + rand))
          scrambled += rand;
    }

    System.out.println(scrambled);


}
}
```

Output:
Enter a word: 
**computer**
emotucrp

But if I enter the word "continue", the program goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: Your code will not work for words that have the same letter more than once. Continue contains the letter `n` twice.

Comment: "continue" has two 'n's.

Comment: Try debugging it. You'll learn more that way.

Comment: If you view the string as an array of chars and then shuffle it. (two random numbers and swap them, then it's just a matter of finding the number of times to swap to give a decent amount of scrambling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word `continue` has two `n`s in it, so your program never adds the second `n` to the scrambled string and therefore never stops. [This question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316674/how-to-shuffle-characters-in-a-string) has various code samples to scramble words like you are trying to do.