# How to shuffle a string without using Arrays or Vectors?

Tags: java

So, in school we've got this homework where I have to show a  shuffled a word and the person have to guess what it's written. However, we haven't been taught about shuffling words and our professor told us to *google it*. So far, I've read some articles but they're not working, at least in my case.

So, I'd be really happy if someone of you could tell me how to and explain it to me - if you want so.

*Neither arrays nor vectors can be used.* Thank you!

Comment: What does shuffling a word mean to you here?  Why can't you use an array?

Comment: Please provide said articles and what you saw when you tried them

Comment: [This doesn't use arrays or vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3316795/2308683)

Answer (score 0):

Well a String is fundamentally an array wrapped in a class, so that's kind of a funny requirement, but you can just shuffle one character at a time for n iterations. Fill in the line where I've left a comment

```
Random r = new Random (System.currentTimeMillis());
For (int i = 0; i < n; i ++) { // n is your number of iterations 
  int idx = r.nextInt(str.length);
  // use String .substring to move the character at index idx to the end of the string 
}
```

Comment: In Java, a `String` is not an array. They're entirely different types. Remember, Java is a strongly-typed language.

Comment: @LewBloch I have clarified: "a String is fundamentally an array wrapped in a class"

Answer (score 0):

Since its an assignment, will give basic explanation and leave you to the implementation.

What you can do is to create/write a swap function`swap(posA,posB,string)`, that takes two parameter, `posA` and `posB` and swap the character in the respectives position in the String 'string'. Loop through all the characters and generate two random number (positions) in each case, then swap the characters:

```
for (char element : string ){
   swap(genRandom(), genRandom(), string);
}
```

where `genRandom()` is a random number generator within the range of the length of the string.

Comment: This won't work because strings are immutable in Java.